# How to add meta data to WordPress posts?

Tags: post-meta

In a clean WordPress installation, how do you add meta keywords and meta description in head tag of my WordPress pages? There aren't any fields for these.

I don't want to touch my code since I'm new to WordPress. I want to do this only by WordPress itself.

Comment: did you checked WordPress's Custom MetaBox. if not check it out. then follow @batz answer.  
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Comment: As to your question's update, you can't do it without changing your code or installing a plugin. Choose between these two.

Comment: @batz: Nope - I'm referring to turning on the option if it isn't there. Or, from what the answers and comments, it looks like it really isn't even an option (without modifying code).

Comment: You're welcome. I also update the answer and proposed a plugin.

Comment: Yes - that's what I thought. Just wanted a confirmation WP can't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are trying to add metadata to the header, such as Open Graph. To do so, you can hook into `wp_head` and output your content there directly. Add this piece of code to your theme's (or your child theme's) `functions.php` file:

```
//Hook to wp_head
add_action('wp_head','add_my_metadata');
function add_my_metadata(){
    // Echo any content your wish here. Replace this with what you want.
    echo '<meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1, Keyword2"/>';
}
```

Notice, that your theme must have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in its `header.php` file in order for you to be able to output any content there.

### UPDATE

If you are new to WordPress, you can install a plugin. There are plenty of known plugins that can do this for you, the most distinguished one is [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) which automatically does this for you.

Comment: I definitely echo Jack's recommendation to simply use Yoast SEO plugin.

Comment: @belinus: I knew about Yoast. Seems like this basic functionality would be built in.

Comment: @4thSpace It's actually not that easy to do such thing. When it comes to custom post types, taxonomies, and stuff like this, it gets harder and harder. I tried to do this myself once, but just gave up since it was consuming too much of my time, generating custom content for keyword based on content, and more.

Comment: @4thSpace It's not handled in WordPress Core because people will use it differently so they cannot cover most use cases without bloating code. Plus no search engine uses the `keywords` meta element anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you meaning how you could add the html tags to header:

1. You could or copy the file header.php into a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
2. Or use [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) into [wp_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head)